# Given, y=x^3 - 2x+3, Find the equation of the tangent at at x =2

Tags: slope

I am having trouble with the following question:
Given, $y=x^{3}-2x+3$, Find the equation of the tangent at at x =2.

I tried doing $y_{2}-y_{1}=m(x_{2}-x_{1})$. Then I plugged 2 into the equation and got 7 which I used as my m value but I am not really sure what to do.

Comment: Hint: Use derivatives.

Comment: The steps to take the derivatives of a polynomial is to multiply each term's coefficient by the variable's exponent then reduce the exponent by 1
. Constants become 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $y=x^3-2x+3$.

Take the derivative:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2-2$$

Substitute $x=2$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=3\cdot2^2-2=10$$

So, the slope is $10$. Consider that it passes the curve at $x=2\rightarrow y=7$. Therefore, the tangent is $(2,7)$ and the equation is
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)\\
y-7=10(x-2)\\
y=10x-20+7\\
y=10x-13$$

Comment: For some reason, the answer sheet says: y = 10x-13

Comment: @Timmy Sorry, my mistake. Now it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent at $f(x)$ in $x=x_0$ is given by

$$y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

in this case $f(2)=7$ and $f'(2)=10$ thus

$$y=7+10(x-2)\implies y=10x-13$$

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the tangent is given by the derivative, so you need to take $\frac {dy}{dx}$ and evaluate it at $x=2$ to get the slope.  Then $(x_1,y_1)$ is the point on the curve at $x=2$ and you have your linear equation.

Comment: I have never heard of derivatives before. I am in grade 12, is derivitives supposed to be taught in grade 12?

Comment: If you are asked this question they should have been taught.  It is a big enough subject you wouldn't have missed it.